# How to select Bezier spline?

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I need a way to check, whether user clicked a Bezier spline. My current approach is to split it to segments and then check, whether the hit point is near enough to one of these segments (near enough in terms of mathematical point-to-segment distance method). But this method has its drawbacks:

[image: Bezier selection]

As you see, points marked by red dots will not be treated as active, though they should be. Of course, I can increase number of segments, but that will actually make the solution worse, because there will be a lot more gaps between active areas.

How can I reliably check, whether user clicked area near Bezier spline?

Note, that I post this on StackOverflow instead of its Math counterpart, because I actually need more reliable heuristics than mathematical solution (the latter mostly probably will be to slow to be used in my program, these checks have to be done in real time, during mouse move).

Comment: how about indicate gaps by the curve shape and set additional segments only to fill the gaps?

Comment: btw how do you get the points for the simplified red line?

Comment: Physics nerd turned c# programmer here I was attracted by the Bezier spline. 

I think it depends on what your definition of area near Bezier spline? Like do you want to know? Which of the three lines the user wanted to click? Or do you care more about him pulling it or something? Maybe you could do the distance not from the red segments but from the curved line?  I agree adding a filler into the red dot areas wouldnt be so hard, but I am a bit unclear how you would define it.

Comment: TL;DR: User clicks in the red circles. Did he wanted to click the black spline or not? The algorithm has to decide, whether the spline should be chosen or not (remember, it's very hard to click the spline *precisely*) Red polyline is used auxiliary, only to answer the first question.

Comment: @JPack i thought of checking the overlapping of the cornerpoints of the areas. Then define a rectangle with the both non-overlapping corners and half of the "thickness" of an  area. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding point-point distance calculation between the red dots and the line segment cross points? 
With the same distance you use in the point-to-segment distance calculation, it should fill the gaps and work better.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should have been a comment, but I'm not yet allowed to comment, so I post it as answer.

Have you tried measuring against the control point polygon of the bezier curve instead of the bezier curve itself? A bezier curve lies inside the convex hull of its control points. If your bezier curves are not too close to each other it might be sufficient to check if the user clicked inside (or close to) the hull of the control points.

Comment: Upvote for the prefix, I've been there and posted the same thing. Appreciate the caring for the websites rules.

Comment: In my case this is only one Bezier spline. Though I didn't know, that a spline lies inside convex hull of its control points, (+1 for that),  such polygon might cover too big area (in terms of user experience). I will keep that in mind though if my current algorithm becomes too complex and will take too much time to evaluate in real time.